# Django template tag can access string variable but can't call a table function?

Tags: django-templates, django-tables2

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/ you should be able to call a function from a tag as long as it takes no arguments.
I tried this:

```
class TaskTable(Table):
    test = "test"
    def give_aids():
        return "aids"
    def give_tuple():
        return ('y', 'e', 'e', 't',)
    class Meta:
        template_name = 'some_template.html'
```

Then, in the corresponding template file, i attempted to access these like so.

```
{{table.test}}
{{table.give_aids}}
{% for char in table.give_tuple %}
{{char}}
{% endfor %}
```

Upon rendering the template "test" is displayed, while "aids" and "yeet" aren't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I get for being a monkey at python. I'm not passing "self" to the methods. Sorry for wasting your time xD